# Don't download an existing file with axel

Tags: download, resume-download

I have an script that reads some urls and get them to axel to download them. I want stop script on sometimes and resume it further. Axel can resumes file downloading. So if I press Ctrl+C when downloading, the next time, it starts from the resume of file.

but axel doesn't check that the file existed. So it appends ".0" to the end of file name and start downloding it twice. How I can tell to axel if the file with same name existed, skip that and don't downloading it??

Comment: axel uses an [FILE_NAME].st besides the main downloading file which has the state of downloaded file, if you resume it finds the state file and fetches the next bytes

Answer (score 13):

Update, some years later:

If you're using a newer axel, then please simply use the no-clobber option `-c`, instead of implementing it manually as described here!

---

If you want to make sure axel will resume, as it does per file name and not per url, you should use a deterministic name for the file:

```
axel -o NAME_OF_EXISTING_FILE
```

If you want to check if file exists

```
if [ -f $FILE ]; then
   echo "File $FILE exists."
    # operation related to when file exists, aka skip download
else
   echo "File $FILE does not exist." 
   # operation related to when file does not exists
fi
```

In case of axel, you want to start download if...

1. You do not have that file localy, or
2. You have a partial download, so

   ```
    function custom_axel() {

    local file_thingy="$1"
    local url="$2"
    if [ ! -e "$file_thingy" ]; then
        echo "file not found, downloading: $file_thingy"
        axel -avn8 "$url" -o "$file_thingy"
    elif [ -e "${file_thingy}.st" ]; then
        echo "found partial download, resuming: $file_thingy"
        axel -avn8  "$url" -o "$file_thingy"
    else
        echo "already have the file, skipped: $file_thingy"
    fi

    }
   ```

This could go into ~/.bashrc or into /usr/bin/custom_axel.sh and later:

```
while read URL; do
    name=$(basename "$URL") # but make sure it's valid.
    custom_axel "$name" "$URL"
done < /my/list/of/files.txt
```

Comment: This is the correct answer now, with the caveat of that the `-c` option will ONLY resume download correctly when a `.st` file is present in the same folder. This file is created by axel during the download and is removed once it is completed. If the `.st` file is not there, axel will do nothing to verify the file before concluding `already there; not retrieving.`.

Answer (score 5):

Axel use a state file, named with a .st extension.
It is regularly updated during download.
When axel is started, it first checks for <file> and <file.st>. If found, download is resumed where it stopped.
Which version do you have ? I got Axel version 2.4 (Linux) and it resume correctly after a CTRL+C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use axel with `-c` flag. From `axel --help`:

```
--no-clobber        -c  Skip download if file already exists
```

(Version 2.17.11)